# Does the WTFPL free the author from liability?

Tags: licensing

A group of us were wondering whether or not to go with CC0 or WTFPL because the CC0 explicitly states lack of liability.

Does the WTFPL, if used properly, also free the author(s) from liability of usage?

Comment: The WTFPL doesn't say anything at all about legal liability.  How can it free you from liability if it doesn't address it at all?  Moreover, I wouldn't consider the WTFPL authoritative in any way with respect to creating an actual license.

Answer (score 3):

No. if WTFPL is used as it is, it does not free the author from liabilities. Check the answer for `Why is there no “no warranty” clause?` in [FAQ](http://www.wtfpl.net/faq/).

You are required to add (explicitly) `NO WARRANTY` clause.